# Nodejs: Streaming audio to response

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, audio-streaming, amazon-polly

I am using ExpressJs, and trying make a service for converting text to speech using Amazon Polly.
So I cut the text into sentences and send them to Polly, and when I receive the result Buffer, I pipe it to the response.

The problem is, I tried too many things and every time, I listen to the first sentence only, then the request get ended (while I don't ended it until the very end).

Here are some of what I have tried:

```
let readable = new Stream.Readable()
readable._read = () => {}
let bufs = []
Polly.synthesizeSpeech(chunk, voice).then((data)=>{
    var stream = new Stream.PassThrough()
    stream.end(data)
    stream.pipe(pipe, {end: false})

    readable.push(data)
    readable.pipe(res, {end: false})

    stream.on('end', ()=>{
        if (index == content.length - 1) { // last sentence
            let buf = Buffer.concat(bufs)
            res.write(buf)
            res.end()
        }
    })
})
```

So I tried `Stream.PassThrough()`, `Stream.Readable()` and concatenating the buffers then write then at once to the response.
And every time I find the same, you can just listen to the first sentence.

and this is how I test it:

```
<audio controls>
      <source src="https://localhost:8080/api/transcripe?voice=Salli&url=https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/25/elon-musk-mark-zuckerberg-artificial-intelligence/" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

How could I stream, and listen to the whole text?

Comment: Where are you setting the content type in your server response?  Show a network trace... chances are you aren't handling caching for subsequent range requests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a chrome problem, not nodejs.
It works fine on Firefox.

Will post the solution after I find it.